# Stop printer jobs from terminal

Tags: terminal, printing, printer

I am working with an old CentOs version (5.0) that is not really my machine.

Recently, for some dark reasons, I have problems in printing.

The jobs rest in queue, and I cannot cancel them from the bar icon.

I have tried with some terminal commands (`cancel -a` ask for a password, which I don't have, `lpq -a`, and other things of what I don't really know the meaning), but the job is still stuck at the printer icon.

Do you have any suggestions?

---

The image explains my situation and how the first answer can not fix this.

`crony` is the name of another printer, while the one I use is `crust`.

[image]

Comment: If you have CUPS web-interface running I'd try to cancel a print job from there. Usually it works for me http://localhost:631

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To cancel a print job :

1. List all jobs:

   ```
   lpq 
   Rank   Owner/ID              Class  Job Files       Size Time 
   active bob                   A      11  zarma.txt   8000 10:12:10
   ```
2. Delete the job by it's id, which is 11 here:

   ```
   lprm 11
   ```

You must be `root` to delete jobs that you don't have initiated.

If the printer is not the default printer, add the `-P` option, e.g.

```
    lpq -P crust
    lprm -P crust …
```

---

Supposing that :

If `lpq` didn't show any printing jobs, it is because they are no more in the queue.

If as shown by the screen copy the printer status is unknown, perhaps the line  remains because the tool is missing the printing status.

Perhaps the job has already been submitted and the job will be cancelled, when the communication with the printer is established.

Is it a link problem or is the printer down?

Comment: Thanks for your post, but it does not work. I have edited my post to explain it better.

Comment: @Py-ser To select which printer to act on, use the -P option (see my edit)

Comment: @Gilles, it is not a matter of selection, it is a matter that the `lpq` command does not see any job in queue, but the printer window does!

Comment: @Py-ser By running `lpq` with no argument, you ask it to list the jobs on the default printer, which for you is `crony`. So it doesn't show any job. There is no contradiction with the printer window which shows a job on a different printer (`crust`).

Comment: @Gilles, I see. So how can I print on terminal the jobs of another printer? I tried `lpq -P crust`, but the output is the same (with just a different printer name).

Comment: @polym It was one supposition that included questions and guesses and your edit transformed the all into a mix of disordered assertion and supposition. I disagree your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just for others that end up here:

On new linux versions, there works the simple command `cancel`:

> The `cancel` command cancels print jobs.  If no destination or id is specified, the currently printing job on the default destination is canceled.